Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. How is it resolve
I don't understand what is problem in my todo list make.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Task from './component/Task'

function App() {

    const [task, setTask] = useState();
    const [taskList, setTaskList] = useState([]);

    function AddTask() {
        setTaskList([...taskList, { task: task }]);
        setTask('');
    }
    return (
        <div>

            <h1>List</h1>
            <input type='text' placeholder='fill your tast' onChange={(e) => { setTask(e.target.value) }} />
            <button onClick={AddTask}>Add</button>
            {
                taskList.map((task, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <Task key={i} task={task.task} />
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )

}

export default App;




another component

import React from 'react';

function Task(task) {
    return (
        <div>
            {task.item}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Task;

You should give the key to the component you actually return in the mapping, not their children. So in your case that would be "div". Or alternatively you could remove the div and return "Task" directly.

The key prop is required when you are mapping an array as JSX element.
Notice how i used key in div and not in Task, this means you'll need to use key property in the higher level elemen.
const [task, setTask] = useState();
const [taskList, setTaskList] = useState([]);

function AddTask() {
    setTaskList([...taskList, { task: task }]);
    setTask('');
}
return (
    <div>

        <h1>List</h1>
        <input type='text' placeholder='fill your tast' onChange={(e) => { setTask(e.target.value) }} />
        <button onClick={AddTask}>Add</button>
        {
            taskList.map((task, i) => {
                return (
                    <div key={`${i}`}>
                        <Task task={task.task} />
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }
    </div>
)

